# Is my slide-to-anchor jQuery routine a correct use of JavaScript, or is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm currently working on a project with a one page design that'll slide up and down between sections on an `<a href>` link...

Currently, i have it written as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('top')">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('artistsmaterials')">artist's materials</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('pictureframing')">picture framing</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('gallery')">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('contactus')">contact us</a></li>  
</ul>
```

...with the most relevant portion being the links:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('contactus')">
```

Then in a .js file I have:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Is this ok? Or should this be done a different way?

Comment: You should not be using inline JavaScript, use event binding instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach would be to not use anchors in this case, you can simplify your markup and code like this:

```
<ul id="scrollMenu">
    <li rel="top">home</li>
    <li rel="artistsmaterials">artist's materials</li>
    <li rel="pictureframing">picture framing</li>
    <li rel="gallery">gallery</li>
    <li rel="contactus">contact us</li>  
</ul>
```

And then this script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#scrollMenu li").click(function() {        
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+$(this).attr("rel")).offset().top},'slow');
  });
});
```

This adds a click handler to your `<li>` elements telling them to use their `rel=""` property to know where to scroll to.  Just change your CSS around to point to the `<li>` elements instead of `<a>` and you're all set.